# Toggles on Edit Email Settings not saving

Tags: bug, user-accounts

When I go to `Edit profile and settings` -> `Edit Email Settings` and toggle almost any option (e.g. `Features & Announcements`, `The Overflow`, `Tips & Reminders`). If i then reload the page or click the `Save` button on the `Email Address` section. All altered toggles revert back to unselected. I have checked with other people i know and not everyone is having this issue. I would really like to be able to manage my account but the only thing I can do is adjust my `Inbox` setting.

Comment: No repro here. Tried it on "The Overflow" and all is well.

Comment: What browser are you using and on which OS? Do you have any plugis/ user scripts running.

Comment: I have tried in Chrome, FireFox, and IE. With my account all behave the same and do not save. Using same browsers but for someone else's account, there are no problems. All changes save fine. I am sure its with my account somehow. I have tried from multiple computers and multiple browsers to eliminate both of them.